# Rails5 Select checkboxes form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I want my user to select out of a pre-filtered list of model instances.

Let's say `@pages` is an ActiveRecord Relationship of multiple pages.

Then in my view I want to display a form where the user can select them:

```
[X] Page One
[ ] Page Two
[ ] Page Three
```

And in my next controller action to be the params something like

```
selection => [12345 => true, 23456 => false, 56788 => false]
```

Where the numbers are the ids. Or even better the instances themselves.

The only thing I can figure out is

```
<%= form_with url: validate_pages_path do |form| %>
  <% Page.all.each do |page| %>
    <%= check_box_tag page.id %>
    <%= label_tag page.name %>
  <% end %>
  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

But then I end up with a params mess like

```
 {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"...", "992936610"=>"1", "992936644"=>"1", "commit"=>"Save "}
```

I don't have a model that nests `pages` that is definitely making it quite tricky

Comment: the trick is to create a hidden field for each ID with value = `false` before each of your other `check_box` with value = `true`. If a checkbox is checked, it will be overriding the previous hidden input value `false` for that id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I suggested in my comment, here the code in your case:

```
<%= form_with url: validate_pages_path do |form| %>
  <% Page.all.each do |page| %>
    # new stuff below
    <%= hidden_field_tag "pages[#{page.id}]", false %>
    <%= check_box_tag "pages[#{page.id}]", true %>
    # /new stuff above
    <%= label_tag page.name %>
  <% end %>
  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

As you can see, we used the name `"pages[page.id]"`, so you should end up having `params[:pages]` which wraps the whole thing.

Comment: Ok nice! 
But then we still end up with the parameter mess, where everything just lingers around there. Any idea how to put that into a hash or something?

Comment: Then I end up with `"pages"=>{"page.id"=>"false"}` instead of an array of ids

Comment: @bnassler sorry I forgot the string interpolation, see my updated answer

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!